# progress jumps from 0 to 1 with ASIHTTPRequest, also AccurateProgress

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I want to show the Progress from a Download.
I want to load an Document and show it in an Webview.

Everything is working, only my progress(the - (void)setProgress:(float)newProgress method) shows up 4 times and says value: 0.000000.

Even the -(void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveBytes:(long long)bytes method jumps from received bytes 1 then to its original size.

What Iam doing wrong?

The Server sends me an Response Header:

```
{
    "Cache-Control" = "private,max-age=0";
    "Content-Length" = 22993;
    "Content-Type" = "application/vnd.ms-word.document.12";
    Date = "Tue, 28 Feb 2012 12:20:18 GMT";
    Etag = "\"{EA1043C4-BE59-4775-AAC0-D25141572D94},2\"";
    Expires = "Mon, 13 Feb 2012 12:20:18 GMT";
    "Last-Modified" = "Wed, 13 Apr 2011 11:04:06 GMT";
    MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices = "14.0.0.4762";
    "Persistent-Auth" = true;
    "Public-Extension" = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/repl-2";
    ResourceTag = "rt:EA1043C4-BE59-4775-AAC0-D25141572D94@00000000002";
    SPRequestGuid = "e4791157-4b6f-4961-84e1-2979d23bf5bc";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
    "Set-Cookie" = "WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated={d2e7fd96-aad9-429d-b85d-64a13026c693}; path=/, WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated={d2e7fd96-aad9-429d-b85d-64a13026c693}; path=/, WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated={d2e7fd96-aad9-429d-b85d-64a13026c693}; path=/";
    "X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
    "X-SharePointHealthScore" = 0;
}

ASIHTTPRequest *asiRequestTemp = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: self.documentURL]];
[asiRequestTemp setTimeOutSeconds:10];


[self setAsiRequestDocumentViewer:asiRequestTemp];

[asiRequestDocumentViewer setDelegate:self];


[asiRequestDocumentViewer setUseKeychainPersistence:YES];
[asiRequestDocumentViewer setUseSessionPersistence:YES];


 [asiRequestDocumentViewer setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
    [asiRequestDocumentViewer setDownloadProgressDelegate:self];

    [asiRequestDocumentViewer setDownloadDestinationPath:mediaPath];
    [asiRequestDocumentViewer startAsynchronous];
```

Whats wrong with that, even the Content Length is shown up!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem. How large is the data you're downloading? Have you checked how it's coming in? ASIHTTPRequest does't start updating your progress download until it has successfully downloaded your headers, and I've noticed that if the data is small enough to come in in two or three bursts, setProgress will be called only with a value of 0.0 and 1.0.